# Numerically finding the smallest positive root of a function

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

I have some formulas in the form $$a - x^2 + f(x), \quad x \geqslant 0$$ where $f(x)$ is a smooth periodic function. For example when $f(x)$ is a sinusoid, that looks something like this:

[image]

There can be one or more positive roots, arbitrarily close together, and I need to numerically approximate the first positive root. I know the period of $f(x)$.

Basic root-finding methods (Newton's etc) seem not reliable here as they are not guaranteed to find the correct root. How can I approach this problem?

Comment: Just start with $x=0$ and go along necessary direction with the stepsize based on the period of $f(x)$ and you won't miss anything.

Comment: @VsevolodA. I don't know how many peaks/troughs there are in f(x) per period. f(x) can be any smooth periodic function, so I don't know the step-size.

Comment: Well, there is no way to find the right root without exploring $f(x)$ behaviour.

Comment: Even with a basic f=sin(x) there's no fixed step size as the turning points are effected by the x^2 term.

Comment: You start with $x=0$ and run simple newton gradient method. If it fails (no root nearby), you add one period and run it again, and so on.

Comment: Newton's method often finds the wrong roots when applied in this manner, erratically jumping between a few nearby roots as you sweep through x0 values. This finds A root, but not reliably the FIRST root.

Comment: My bad. Instead of Newton's method for finding a root, use it to find minima. If it's less that zero then use it to find the root, otherwise add one period and try again.

Comment: This appears to have the same issue, it jumps erratically between turning points. I don't know of a way to guarantee that I'm not skipping a turning point and therefor missing the first root. I'd be willing to accept the wrong root as long as it's within some (very small) tolerance of the correct one, but I do need a reliable and precise position for first intersection. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: This method with small stepsize cannot skip anything. If you're using someone else code, try fixing maximum stepsize to some fraciton of the period (0.1 maybe).

Comment: You could try an inefficient method, where you pick your favorite root-finding algorithm to first determine *any* positive root. Once you have your two bounds (x=0 and x=root), and suspect that there might be more roots within that bound, you can use any bracketed method to determine those additional roots. You repeat all of this until no more roots are found, in which case you conclude that the previous found root is the smallest positive root. Obviously a slow method, but it works as a temporary workaround at least.